# Windows 11 causes instabilities with bluetooth and wifi, applications get stuck and stutter

Tags: wireless-networking, bluetooth, windows-11, lag

HP EliteBook 830 G5
HP Q78 1.09.01, 16.10.2019
Windows 10.0.22000

I installed Windows 11 about 3 weeks ago. Before, my Laptop ran on Windows 10.

Apps running:

- Office 365 (Word, Excel)
- Chrome
- OneDrive
- OneNote
- Outlook
- Spotify
- Citrix Workspace and Connection Manager (Only in the background for remote desktop but no desktop active)
- Conexant Flow
- HP Hotkey
- Logi Overlay, LogiBolt, LogiOptions
- Skype
- PowerToys
- No particular antivirus software, just Defender
- No VPN
- No games
- 

System conditions:

- CPU between 12 and 50% max
- Memory 63%
- Disk-Usage 0-3 MB/sec
- Network: a few KB on average.

Since upgrading, I'm facing various kinds of instabilities:

- Wifi is unstable and lags and/or the speed drops from 150 mbit/s to ~10, e.g. when browsing different web-sites or using MSFT Teams.
  At the same time, Android devices, connected to the same access point, perform well.
- Whenever there is some network load (only a few KB), e.g. during googling or when OneNote is syncing a notebook, the Bluetooth connection stutters. This happens, e.g., with Sennheiser and Huawei Earbuds.
- Sometimes, Bluetooth seems to stutter when CPU usage increases (but it's less than 50%)
- Sometimes (cannot reproduce the exact circumstances), applications lag or freeze briefly for 1-2 seconds.
- It "feels" like cooperative multitasking, when applications would lag if other apps don't behave well.
- All drivers are up to date according to the HP Support Assistant tool.
- Settings => System => Troubleshoot (Internet, Bluetooth, Incoming Connections, Network Adapter, ...) does not report anything.

I know that this description is quite vague but I really don't know how to pin it down any better.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: What WiFi/BT device do you have.  I know my Intel card in my main machine has had several Windows 11 specific updates released recently.  Do you have an Intel or AMD processor?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Processor is Intel Core i7-85OU. bluetooth: Intel Wireless Bluetooth, Firmware HCI 8.256/LMP 8.256.